# How much of integration theory can be done over Dynkin systems?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a Dynkin system equipped with a probability “measure” which respects complements and countable disjoint unions. How much of integration theory still goes through over $\mathcal{D}$? It is obvious that Fatou's lemma fails. What about the dominated convergence theorem?

I am asking because I have just begun learning measure-theoretic probability and I really do not believe that the intersection of events should have to be an event. I want to find a more believable axiom which implies that the intersection of events is an event, or else come upon an adequate theory which does without the assumption entirely.